# Functions that satisfy a reverse triangle inequality: do they have a name?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}_+$ satisfy
$$f(a) - f(b) \le C f(a - b)$$
$\forall a, b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for some $C \ge 0$. Is there a name for such functions? (I would be happy to have a name for the special case $C=1$.)

Note the similarity to
$$\|x\| - \|y\| \le \|x - y\|$$
which is satisfied by all norms.

Comment: Just a small note: if $C < 1$, then plugging in $a=x$ and $b=0$ yields that $f(x)$ is bounded above by $f(0)/(1-C)$, and if $C>1$ then $f$ is bounded below by this quantity.

Comment: Relabel $a = c + b$ then your inequality reads f(c+b) <= C f(c) + f(b). When C = 1 this is "subadditive"

Comment: There's a name in the case $C = 0$.  :-)

Comment: @StevenGubkin Along similar lines, $a=2x$ and $b=x$ leads to $f(2^n x) \le (1 + C)^n f(x)$.

Comment: For, $h \rightarrow 0$, and any $x$, $f'(x)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \leq Cf'(h)/h=T$. Here, we take $f(0)=0$ and $f(h)/h=f'(0)=T$. and  If, $C<1$, $f(x)-f(0)=f(x)\leq Cf(x)$ implies that $f(x)\leq 0$ for all $x$. And this two can't happen simultaneously. So, $C$ can't be less than $1$, except for zero function.

Comment: From the inequalities $f(x)+f(-x)\geq 0$, $f(y+x)-f(y)\leq Cf(x)$ and $f(y+x-x)-f(y+x)\leq f(-x) \rightarrow f(x+y)-f(y)\geq -Cf(-x)$, with $x \to 0$, we get $Cf'(0)\geq f'(y) \geq Cf'(0) \Rightarrow f'(y)=Cf'(0)$. Hence, $C$ can only be $1$, and the function will be $f(x)=cX , c\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @AlapanDas what about the Euclidean norm?

Comment: @user27182 I have considered only differentiable functions.